# I want the iframe and textarea to be next to each other and center in the middle. How can I do that?

Tags: html, css, iframe, textarea

I want the iframe and textarea to be by each other (think of a square with a line down the middle) and I want it to be located sort of in the middle. How can I do that??

```
iframe{
    width: 80%;
    height: 20vh;

}

textarea{
  width: 80%;
  height: 20vh;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not to sure what you mean by a square with a line in the middle; but I can show you how to put the textarea and iframe side by side.

```
iframe{
width: 70%;
height: 20vh;
display:inline;
 }

 textarea{
 width: 20%;
height: 20vh;
display:inline;
  }
```

Depending on the ratio you want, just change the width. Make sure not to make it 100% , because you have to take in account the margin padding etc..

Answer (score 0):

Enclose them in a div like this:

```
<div>
  <iframe>
  </iframe>

  <textarea>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

and then add css:

```
div {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;  /* centers the children */
}
```

and then style borders and the rest as you wish:

https://jsfiddle.net/5znvwj0g/1/